# Unique elements of list within list in python

Tags: python, list, set, enumerate

We are given a list of animals in different zoos and need to find which zoos have animals that are not in any others. The animals of each zoo are separated by spaces, and each zoo is originally separated by a comma.

I am currently enumerating over all of the zoos to split each animal and create lists within lists for different zoos as such:

```
for i, zoo in enumerate(zoos):
    zoos[i] = zoo.split()
```

However, I then do not know how to tell and count how many of the zoos have unique animals. I figure it is something else with `enumerate` and possibly sets, but cannot get it down exactly.

Comment: Could you add some examples of the data structure?

Comment: It will work better if you show the code and the data, instead of just describing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think `set` is wot You are looking for.

You can add and subtract sets, find their intersections
So all You need to find zoo which set of animals has item which are not in union animal sets of other zoos. If You will substract all other animals from animals in the zoo You got unique animals.

```
zoos = ['mouse,dog', 'dog,tiger,mouse', 'mouse,cat']
for zoo in zoos:
    zoo_animal = set(zoo.split(','))
    other_zoo_animals = set(animal for z in zoos if z != zoo for animal in z.split(','))
    unique_animals = zoo_animal - other_zoo_animals
    if unique_animals:
       print "%s: %s" % (zoo, unique_animals)
```

or You can just find out where each animal lives:

```
zoos = ['mouse,dog', 'dog,tiger,mouse', 'mouse,cat']
animals = {}
for i, zoo in enumerate(zoos):
    zoo_animal = set(zoo.split(','))
    for animal in zoo_animals:
        animals.setdefault(animal, []).append(i)
# Now You can iterate over all animals and find ones which are only present in one zoo
for animal, zoo_list in animals.iteritems():
    if len(zoo_list) == 1:
        print("% lives in %s only" % (animal, zoo_list[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use sets.

A set only have unique items, and everytime you think of unique items in a list, you should think of sets.

Create a set A with the animals of a particular zoo, and a set B with all other animals.
Then iterate to remove every animal in A that is in B too.
The result will be the unique examples.

Try this:

```
def unique_animals(zoo, list_of_zoos):
    animals_in_other_zoos = set()
    for element of list_of_zoos:
        animals_in_other_zoos.add(set(element))
    unique_animals = set(zoo)
    for element in unique_animals:
        if element in animals_in_other_zoos:
            unique_animals.remove(element)
    return unique_animals
```

I could do something more useful to our case, but i would need some code of yours.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do it with a set, but you don't really need to. What you need is to think about how to organize your data, i.e., the data structure.

Here's one way: To find out animals present in only one zoo, you need a list that gives you, for each animal, the zoos that have it. So construct such a list of zoos for each animal (I'd use a dictionary to hold the animal names, but even a regular list will do), and then just look at each animal and pick the ones that list only one zoo.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly you get a string like this:

```
input_date = 'dog dog mouse cat, dog pidgin elephant, zebra cat lion'
zoos = input_date.split(',')

for zoo in zoos:
    zoo_animal = set(zoo.split())
    other_zoo_animals = set(animal for z in zoos if z != zoo for animal in z.split())
    unique = zoo_animal - other_zoo_animals
    if unique:
       print "%s: %s" % (zoo, animals)
```